# private repo installed, but empty in Xcode project

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

this is my **podspec** :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
 spec.name = 'OoTracker'
  spec.version = '1.0.0'
  spec.license = 'Copyright Oodrive'
  spec.source       = { :git => 'https://oogit.oodrive.net/mobile-common/OoTracker.git', :tag => spec.version.to_s }
  spec.summary = 'A small library to track actions and events using the Matomotracker library'
  spec.homepage = 'https://oogit.oodrive.net/mobile-common/TrackerPod/blob/master/README.md'
  spec.author  = { 'Sandy Ludosky' => 's.ludosky@oodrive.com' }
  spec.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'
  spec.osx.deployment_target = '10.0'
  spec.platform = :ios, "9.1"
  spec.swift_version = '4.0'
  spec.source_files = 'Source/*.{h,m,swift}'
  spec.frameworks  = 'UIKit', 'Foundation', 'CoreFoundation'
  spec.dependency 'MatomoTracker', '~> 5.2.0'

  spec.subspec 'OoTracker' do |s|
    s.source_files  = 'Source/**/*.swift'
  end

end
```

and my **Podfile**: the pod is not public so I use the https to point to it

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TrackerExample' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TrackerExample
  pod 'PodName', :git => '******'

  target 'TrackerExampleTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

this is a screenshot of the pod folder. this is completely empty. No files or classes  attached to the pod when I expand the folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa2gL.png)

**Any thoughts ?**

Comment: `Pods/MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker/**/*.{h,m,swift}` Is that the relative path from the podspec file in your private Repo?

Comment: yes it is. This is fine for MatomoTracker though. This one appears in the project that I am testing. This my own private pod that appears to be empty. That is strange. The terminal output does not indicate any error after 'pod install'

Comment: Is the 1.0.0 tag on the git repo pointing at the right version?

Comment: yes this is pointing to the tag 1.0.0. I have edited my post to include the path to the source files (s.source_files  = 'Source/**/*.swift'). now, the podspec does not validate. However, the pod classes files are visible when I import my development pod in a project example.